# Receiving data from multiple pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I am at a loss in my code trying to receive data from 2 pipes - the data comes in but only 1 at a time.....when it should be alternating between the 2 pipes??

all data seems to be in each pipe but spits it all out in 1 go....do i need to add synchronization?

any help would be greatly appreciated

BTW OS is windows 10

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int readFdControl,readFdSim ;
    char readBufferControl[READ_BLOCK_SIZE+1];
    char readBufferSim[READ_BLOCK_SIZE+1];
    ssize_t bytesReadControl;
    ssize_t bytesReadSim;

    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("Display: Expecting 2 arguments, received %i\n", argc);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Display process with PID %i Started \n", getpid());

    readFdControl = atoi(argv[1]);
    readFdSim = atoi(argv[2]);

    sleep(5);

    if (read(readFdSim, readBufferSim, READ_BLOCK_SIZE)>0)
    {
        bytesReadSim = read(readFdSim, readBufferSim, READ_BLOCK_SIZE);
        // if bytesReadSim is positive, bytes have been read from the pipe
        while (bytesReadSim > 0)
        {
            // terminate string in readBufferSim for printing
            readBufferSim[bytesReadSim] = '\0';
            fflush(stdin);
            printf(readBufferSim);
            //close(readFdSim);
            bytesReadSim = read(readFdSim, readBufferSim, READ_BLOCK_SIZE);

        }
    }

    if (read(readFdControl, readBufferControl, READ_BLOCK_SIZE)>0)
    {
        bytesReadControl = read(readFdControl, readBufferControl, READ_BLOCK_SIZE);
        // if bytesReadControl is positive, bytes have been read from the pipe
        while (bytesReadControl > 0)
        {
            // terminate string in readBufferControl for printing
            readBufferControl[bytesReadControl] = '\0';
            printf(readBufferControl);
            bytesReadControl = read(readFdControl, readBufferControl, READ_BLOCK_SIZE);
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        //close(readFdControl);
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Looks like you have one loop to read everything from one, then another loop to read everything from the other. That matches what you describe. Your description of desired behaviour reads like you want one loop checking both alternatingly. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: @Yannosch, that is correct but i have multiple Writes and i want to change the code so I do the following  Sim Write --> Display read. Control Write --> Display read etc etc.....i am unsure how to break out of the loop and read from the next pipe

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell your OS. If possible I suggest to use `select` and non-blocking mode. What's the purpose of the code `if (read(readFdSim, readBufferSim, READ_BLOCK_SIZE)>0) { bytesReadSim = read(readFdSim, readBufferSim, READ_BLOCK_SIZE); /* ... */ }`? The first `read` will (try to) read a buffer of data, then you check if it has read anything, discard the buffer contents and read again one buffer of data.

Comment: Thanks Bodo - I have not dealt with non-blocking mode yet so will have to do will have to do some reading